# Mathematical puzzle 002

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

7 # 4 = 5

1 # 1 = 2

3 # 2 = 5

4 # 3 = ?

> Possible answers: 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5

In this puzzle, I tried to take square of each number and subtracting them or adding them, for instance 49 + 16 = 65 (13 * 5), but each time my result or connection of numbers doesn't suit others. I hope you can solve it. Thanks.
(source: probably Kuark publications, YOS questions.I have seen this questions on [another source](https://14773644510176710490.googlegroups.com/attach/451fe8c534a87/IMG_3457.jpg?part=0.1&view=1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGiPXJD-zP4KNtWN8U8-uJ0ghSTjXy2PyFh6iMWhplPukbylZOmH_Nw1NlcmQv0NRVZtOOM7fL4ciVTgvcCR_7EOxW_ri03zYqFj-j0TrmAhzZZHps), tried to solve myself.)

Comment: This type of puzzle has an infinite number of solutions. I can always fit a polynomial to agree with both the examples and any of the "possible" answers.

Comment: might be on mod 6 sum

Comment: @Galen, thank you for enlightening me but where can I post these types of questions? I have a lot of them which I spend half an hour on each question and I still can't solve. Which site of Stack Exchange fits to these questions? I really don't know. First, I thought about Mathematics, then I published them here. You mean there are a lot of solutions to them, but these are the questions asked by universities in Turkey. If you have solution, please provide one then, I will gladly upvote them. Thanks again.

Comment: *You mean there are a lot of solutions to them*. Not just *a lot* but *infinitely many*.

Comment: *but these are the questions asked by universities in Turkey*. Wow :o I wonder what they're testing; ability to find *some* pattern maybe.

Comment: *Which site of Stack Exchange fits to these questions?* To be fair, Puzzling.SE might be the *best* choice, but as puzzles go, they're problematic in not having a finite set of solutions.

Comment: @Galen, YÖS stands for Yabancı Öğrenci Sınavı, which means International Student Examination. In Turkey universities use these types of questions in addition to Mathematics and Geometry questions in their university admission exams to International students. Yeah, I think they test the pattern finding and logic, maybe.

Comment: @Galen, thank you very much. Here is YÖS exam wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C3%B6s_exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider Oray’s answer in the comments:

> x # y = z, where z = x + y (mod 6).

Thus:

> 7 # 4 => 7+4=11, 11 = 5 mod 6 
>  1 # 1 => 1+1=2, 2 = 2 mod 6 
>  3 # 2 => 3+2=5, 5 = 5 mod 6 
>  4 # 3 => 4+3=7, 7 = 1 mod 6.

So the answer is

> 1.

Comment: Good point. Your answer is logical but let me wait if another versions of the answer come, too. Thank you.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as correct one. Thank you, so much. I have a lot of these type of questions, so if you have solution to my other questions, please provide them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative answer

> A # B = Number of consonants in the spelling of A and B

Examples

> 7 # 4 = **S**e**v**e**n** # **F**ou**r** = 5
>  1 # 1 = O**n**e # O**n**e = 2
>  3 # 2 = **Thr**ee # **Tw**o = 5

So the answer is

> 4 # 3 = **F**ou**r** # **Thr**ee = 5

Comment: This is a really clever answer as well! Nice work.